# Android Room - read запрос в основном потоке вылетает с IllegalStateException

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-room

На [гитхабе гугла](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/) есть андроид приложение, демонстрирующее работу `Room database` совместно с `ViewModel`. Суть приложения заключается в сохранении в БД слов, введенных пользователем. При попытке создать похожее приложение я столкнулся с ошибкой `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.` Ошибка возникает, когда я в основном потоке выполняю read запрос. При создании фонового потока проблема исчезает. Но ведь в примере от гугла запрос тоже выполняется в основном потоке, однако приложение исправно работает. Помогите разобраться, почему?

Ниже будут приведены ключевые строчки из кода от гугл. Архитектура следующая:

- Есть `Activity`, которая создает `ViewModel`.
- `ViewModel` в конструкторе создает `Repository`.
- `Repository` создает экземпляр `RoomDatabase`
- `RoomDatabase` - это абстрактный класс. Используя его, библиотека `Room` генерирует реализацию `DAO`
- Получив реализацию `DAO` в `Repository` выполняется read запрос к БД. Запрос происходит в основном UI потоке. Почему не возникает `IllegalStateException`?

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      private WordViewModel mWordViewModel;

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          //Получить экземпляр ViewModel (основной поток)
          mWordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel.class);
      }
  }


  public class WordViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

      private WordRepository mRepository;

      private LiveData<List<Word>> mAllWords;

      public WordViewModel(Application application) {
          super(application);
          //Создать репозиторий (основной поток)
          mRepository = new WordRepository(application);
          //ViewModel делегирует запрос в Repository
          mAllWords = mRepository.getAllWords();
      }
  }

  class WordRepository {

      private WordDao mWordDao;
      private LiveData<List<Word>> mAllWords;

      WordRepository(Application application) {
          WordRoomDatabase db = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
          //Room генерирует реализацию DAO
          mWordDao = db.wordDao();
          //Используя DAO делаем read запрос в основном UI потоке(!)
          mAllWords = mWordDao.getAlphabetizedWords();
      }
  }

  abstract class WordRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
      //Реализация данного метода автоматически генерируется библиотекой Room
      abstract WordDao wordDao();
  }


  public interface WordDao {
      @Query("SELECT * from word_table ORDER BY word ASC")
      LiveData<List<Word>> getAlphabetizedWords();
  }
  ```

Comment: Если метод Dao возвращает LiveData, то Room должен сам делать чтение не другом потоке и выставлять значение в вернувшейся liveData и к таким методам можно обращаться из UI потока. Может у вас старая версия Room подключена, которая не поддерживает LiveData или вы делаете какие-либо ещё запросы помимо `getAlphabetizedWords`? Попробуйте обновить до последней версии

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вам же явно пишут, что обращаться к базе данных из UI потока нельзя.

В Room при создании бд можно добавить свойство allowMainThreadQueries() для доступа из UI потока, но это крайне не рекомендуется.

При использовании LiveData все обращение к бд скрыто под капотом, а на UI потоке вы просто подписываетесь на изменения в базе данных, потому там это легитимно.